# Wordpress post custom field image download and set it to featured image

Tags: wordpress, post, field, meta

i have posts with contains image url of external source in custom filed. i want to download it to my own server and set it to featured image. I searched but not got any solution.
Example of my post custom fileld

```
Name               Value
image              example.com/123.jpg
```

Any help is very thankful.

Comment: why not do it manually? what have you tried already? this sounds like something easy to find with a search engine.

Comment: i have 20000 such posts, so its impossible to do manually. i am also searching on internet